# Script Error : Sys.ArgumentException

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am facing a issue. My web site which is working fine when opening in below version of IE 10 browsers, doesn't work in IE 10. 
Giving Error

```
Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors.
Parameter name: element
```

and here is the code in `scriptResource`

```
if (type.inheritsFrom(Sys.UI.Behavior) || type.inheritsFrom(Sys.UI.Control)) {
        if (!element) throw Error.argument('element', Sys.Res.createNoDom);
    }
```

This is only happening in IE10 and works fine on all other browsers. Another things that I have noticed is that when I run the same page with IE10 "Compatibility View", than it works.
Can any one help me ?